# Styles and Resources in App.xaml won't apply to controls at run-time in Visual Studio Extension

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio

I'm building a visual studio extension and i'm trying to use some application wide styles i created. Usually, in a visual studio generated WPF application there would be an App.xaml in which you can specify application resources.

When creating the extension, one of these documents was not created. I assumed i would be able to add my own and be able to use resources from it as i pleased. I made one and i am able to access its resources in other .xaml's (see a small snippet below)

```
<Application xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" 
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         x:Class="Applcation.App">
<Application.Resources>
    <BitmapImage x:Key="CrossIcon" UriSource="Resources/CrossIcon.png" />
    <BitmapImage x:Key="ErrorIcon" UriSource="Resources/ErrorIcon.png" />
    <BitmapImage x:Key="FlareLogo30" UriSource="Resources/Flare Logo H30.png" />
    <BitmapImage x:Key="PlussIcon" UriSource="Resources/PlussIcon.png" />
    <BitmapImage x:Key="WarningIcon" UriSource="Resources/WarningIcon.png" />
    <BitmapImage x:Key="ThumbsUpIcon" UriSource="Resources/ThumbsUpIcon.png" />

</Application.Resources>
```

I can then go ahead and use these in the designer, and they will display correctly.

```
<Image Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Name="Image" Source="{DynamicResource WarningIcon}" Margin="10,10,10,10"/>
```

The issue comes when i launch the visual studio debug instance, and load up my extension, none of these resources appear to be accessible, as images wont show up, and styles wont be applied. These images are also specified as resources in their build action.

Presumably there is something else i have to do in order to register my global resources. I have Google'd around but have not been able to find any documentation on the subject. What do i have to do in order to get these resources recognizable at run-time?

Comment: Try changing the URIs to more explicit paths: e.g. `"pack://application:,,,/ReferencedAssembly;component/Subfolder/ResourceFile.xaml"` https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970069.aspx

Comment: I'll give it a go, but as explained it's not just image files that aren't being applied. Styles are also not being applied as well EDIT: Just tried using an explicit path as you suggested, which unfortunately did not work either.

Answer (score 1):

In the end i have gone with using a basic ResourceDictionary which i have included in all of my xaml's. This loads the images and styles correctly.